# Using Array Walk Within A Class

Tags: php, class

I am having a small programming issue.  I am trying to execute a function within a class and I have an array that I am using array_walk to execute a function on each variable within that array.  The issue is that the function I am executing is a method within the same class.  I have looked over my code however cannot find what the issue is.  Please let me know what a possible solution to this error is or if you see something I am not seeing.

Currently it is not even executing the function `escape()`.  I purposely added a ' in the status variable as I want it to be escaped, but it is done not.

A little background: This is a database class I am building and the `prepare()` method will help escape variables in the query before it is executed.  I removed some code that is not relevant to this issue.

This is the result it is giving me: `UPDATE table_name SET status='I'm doing good!' WHERE username='someone'`

```
<?php
class Database {
    var $weak_escape = false;

    function escape($str) {
    if ($this->weak_escape) return $this->weak_escape($str);
    else return $this->sql_escape($str);
    }

    function weak_escape($str) {
    return addslashes($str);
    }

    function sql_escape($str) {
    return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
    }

    function prepare($query) {
    $args = func_get_args();
    array_shift($args);
    array_walk($args, array(&$this, 'escape'));
    return vsprintf($query, $args);
    }
}

$db = new Database();
$username = "someone";
$status = "I'm doing good!";
echo $db->prepare("UPDATE table_name SET status='%s' WHERE username='%s'", $status, $username);
?>
```

Comment: I think should be like this $db = new Database(); And I am pretty sure if not already, real soon passing by reference is depreciated.

Comment: Yeah that is just my bad habit, in the final code it has variables there, when typing it in to this website I forgot that part.  Thanks though, I fixed the example above.  Obviously that doesn't fix the issue though.

Comment: where is the escape function being performed? Edit:Never mind, i see it. though I don't think you need to ue an & there. $this should already refer to the class no?

Comment: I tried it with an without, and unforuntely it did not make a difference.

Comment: your escape function is firing and working. got something to do with other parts of your code.

Comment: Dr.Molle's method ended up working.  But only returning without declaring a variable it didn't modify the inputted data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to modify the argument(reference of array-item), this isn't done if you return it:

```
function escape(&$str)
{
  $str=addslashes($str);
}
```

Comment: That ended up doing the trick.  Thank you, normally I do that but I figured I would try to reduce the amount of code, however less code ended up hurting me.  Normally I don't use the & but it obviously makes a difference.

Answer (score 2):

I'de make my escape function static, cause it's the same for every instance:

```
class Database {
    static function escape($str) {
       return addslashes($str);
    }

    function prepare($query) {
      $args = func_get_args();
      array_shift($args);
      array_walk($args, array('Database', 'escape'));  //Look here
      return vsprintf($query, $args);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: I have a feeling that will work with the example I gave however my actual code it doesn't work because within `function escape($str)` it makes a $this reference to another method within the class.  Let me try to update my example above to show what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is what you are looking for.
I did this:

```
class Database {
    function escape($str) {
       return addslashes($str);
    }

    function prepare($query) {
    $args = func_get_args();
    $args[1] = $this->escape($args[1]);
    array_shift($args);
    array_walk($args, array($this, 'escape'));
    return vsprintf($query, $args);
    }
}

$db = new Database();
$username = "someone";
$status = "I'm doing good!";
print $db->prepare("UPDATE table_name SET status='%s' WHERE username='%s'", $status, $username);
```

got result:

```
UPDATE table_name SET status='I\'m doing good!' WHERE username='someone'
```